# Getting only city names from autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I want user to select only city name from *Google Maps Autocomplete API*. It's not a problem if cities listed with their countries but when user selects a city I don't want to get anything after comma. Is there any way to cut that country name out of selection?

```js
var placeSearch, fromLocation, whereLocation;
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcWtvH1d2_fltDXR0aC7brC56QQZqXaWA&libraries=places&callback=activatePlacesSearch";
document.head.append(script);

function activatePlacesSearch() {
  fromLocation = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('fromLoc')), {
      types: ['(cities)']
    });

  whereLocation = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('whereLoc')), {
      types: ['(cities)']
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md align-items-end">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="#">From</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <div class="icon" style="width: 0px;"><span class="icon-my_location"></span></div>
      <input id="fromLoc" name="from" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md align-items-end">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="#">Where</label>
    <div class="form-field">
      <div class="icon" style="width: 0px;"><span class="icon-map-marker"></span></div>
      <input id="whereLoc" name="where" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Where">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) you can use the `fields` attribute, although I'm not sure if that will give you the level of control you're looking for

Comment: @freefaller How? I do not see "Fields showing only city but not country"

Comment: It's a fair question, and one I can't answer, sorry... just wanted to point you at the docs, in case you hadn't already seen it

Comment: @freefaller yes, I've also seen that in documentation but unfortunetaly it doesn't explain how to use it

Comment: To customize how the results appear, without dirty hacks, use the [Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service) from the Maps API v3.